# ($(window).scrollTop() > not working on IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

I am using below JS code to fix header at the top for mobile only.
means if screen is scrolled for 80px  css classes will be replaced.
working on android  and PC but no luck on Ios.
any suggestions?

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {
        $('.navbar-right').addClass('custom-fixed-top');
    }
    else{
        $('.navbar-right').removeClass('custom-fixed-top');
    }
}
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="mid-container">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed hidden-xs" data-toggle="collapse"
                    data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="logo"></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="true" style="">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a class="hdr-orng-btn" href="#">受付時間</a></li>
                <li class="hidden-xs"><a class="" href="#">10：00～19：00</a></li>
                <li><a class="num" href="tel:03-0000-0000">TEL　03-0000-0000</a></li>
                <li><a class="hdr-grn-btn" href="#contact_form">お問い合わせ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.navbar-nav.custom-fixed-top{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 0 15px 15px;
margin: 0;
z-index: 2;
background-color:#fff;
left:0;
```

}
this is the code.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a CSS related problem? If the code is executing on Android and PC it's probably doing the same on iOS, but the results are probably not identical. Could you post the rest of your code?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.just added my HTML code.

Comment: Can you include the CSS for `custom-fixed-top` also.

Comment: CSS code added above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this might seem far fetched *but...*

Try add the following to your CSS in your html tag if they're on IOS:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can be your `if` verification of viewport screen width with 768, verify if you use some screen above that size.
I try replicate your code here, but `$(window).scrollTop()` works fancy here for me.

[Image with your code on google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUelP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this;

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() > 80) {...
```

To this;

```
if ($(body).scrollTop() > 80) {...
```

If that then works on ios, then that's the issue, so to cover both devices/browsers implement something like this;

```
var scrollentity = $('html,body');
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPod|iPhone|iPad)/)) 
{ scrollentity = $('body') }
else  { scrollentity = $('html,body') }
scrollentity .scrollTop() > 80) {...
```

Hope it helps.